# 302 "Found" page when trying to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

I'm am trying to set up a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS for a client site. I added the following code to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But doing so brought users to a 302 "Found" page when visiting HTTP pages on the site, instead of redirecting them to the HTTPS version.

I'm trying to figure out why this happens, and how to fix the issue to get the desired outcome. The site already forces a `www` subdomain - which could be contributing to the issue..?

Using apache on an Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you have a conflict with other directives. You are missing the `L` (`last`) flag from your rule, so processing continues through the file instead of triggering an immediate redirect.

You should also be explicit and include the `R` flag, which you will need to do when this is changed to a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Note also that this rule must be near the top of the file *before* any existing rewrites.

For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

I changed the *pattern* from `(.*)` to `^` which is more efficient and since you are not using the backreference in the *substitution*.

#### Detail on the `L` and `R` flags...

The `L` (`last`) flag prevents any mod_rewrite rules that follow being processed during the current pass by the rewrite engine. Effectively saying this is the `last` rule (although, to complicate matters, that's not necessarily the case when combined with internal rewrites in a *directory* context). In the case of an external redirect, processing stops completely and the redirect response is sent back to the client. The `L` (or `END`) flag nearly always needs to be used with external redirects. (There is no difference between `L` and `END` when it comes to external redirects. `END` is only available on Apache 2.4+)

The `R` flag triggers an external redirect. ie. A redirect response is sent back to the client with a `Location` HTTP response header. If an HTTP response code is not stated then it defaults to a 302 (temporary) redirect. You need to state the HTTP response code to make it a 301 (permanent) redirect - which an HTTP to HTTPS redirect should ultimately be. Note that 301 (permanent) redirects are cached by the browser (and possibly intermediary) caches, so can make testing problematic. For this reason always test with 302 (temp) redirects first.

If an `R` flag is not included and you specify an absolute URL in the *substitution* string (as you did here) then - on most systems - it actually defaults to a 302 (temp) redirect. But you should be explicit and include the `R` flag to formerly declare your meaning.

Reference, from the Apache docs:

- `L` flag -  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l
- `R` flag - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Comment: I think this is the correct answer,  and thank you for improving the rewrite rule as well. For posterity, could you go into exactly what the L and R options are doing here?

Comment: @JillianHoenig I've updated my answer with more detail on the `L` and `R` flags.

Comment: Thank you - appreciate it. I'm going to mark this as the correct answer, because it is. It looks like you grabbed some explanations of the `L` and `R` options from the docs. Honestly it's a little confusing and counterintuitive (assume folks who are reading my questions aren't experts!), so if you wanted to edit your answer to provide a human-readable explanation as to why those options apply specifically to my scenario, that would be greatly appreciate by me and the community!

Comment: @JillianHoenig "It looks like you grabbed some explanations of the L and R options from the docs." - These are all my own words. I did not look up the docs until the end when I added the reference links. "provide a human-readable explanation" - Sorry, I thought I had. What do you find "confusing and counterintuitive"? Basically, you are just missing the `L` flag on that rule. As I said in my first paragraph, the `L` flag indicates this is the "last" rule, so prevents any directives that follow being processed, which might otherwise _change/corrupt_ the redirect - which seemed to be the case.